# Angularjs disabling debug data in production

Tags: angularjs, performance

I'm trying to disable debug data in production server as suggested in the angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production). Adding that I don't really see any improvement in performance and loading time. Here is how my code look in app.js. Is it the right way to do it?

```
angular.module('myApp',['toaster','ui.router','ui.bootstrap','myApp.controllers','myApp.directives','myApp.filters','myApp.services'])
.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

Is there a way to check if debug info is disabled?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't really see any improvement in performance and loading time.

Yes, humans cannot tell the difference for few ms/us.

> Is there a way to check if debug info is disabled?

Yes, check existance of debug info classes.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ng-scope,.ng-binding,.ng-isolate-scope').length === 0
// true
```