# How can I check if debug information is enabled in angular?

Tags: angularjs

One can toggle angulars debug infos by calling

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(debugInfoState);
```

within the config method of an angular app.

Is there a way of checking if debug information is enabled via the console when an app is running in the browser?

Comment: This answer also is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967438/angularjs-disabling-debug-data-in-production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `debugInfoEnabled` function is a setter/getter. It can be checked in a config block.

```
app.config(function ($compileProvider) {
    var debugEnabled = $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled();
    console.log("debugInfoEnabled=", debugEnabled);
});
```

See [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1218).